# JavaScript Tic Tac Toe not running function in forEach

Tags: javascript

Everything in this game works except for a function that checks possible winning combinations and displays who the winner is or a draw. This function works if placed in the addEventListener for clicking on the squares, however it does not work when placed outside of the addEventListener, but still inside the forEach. This will need to be outside addEventListener because the page needs to update as soon as a winning combination is detected (or draw) as opposed needing to click again for the game to update.

```js
const addPlayer = (name, letter) => {
  return {
    name,
    letter
  };
}

//Form creates players and if names are left blank, will make names "Player 1" and "Player 2" by default.
//Will start the game upon clicking submit and hide the form in place of a game display
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  player1 = addPlayer(document.querySelector('#player1Name').value, 'X');
  if (player1.name == '') {
    player1.name = 'Player 1'
  }
  player2 = addPlayer(document.querySelector('#player2Name').value, 'O');
  if (player2.name == '') {
    player2.name = 'Player 2'
  }
  console.log(player1.name)
  console.log(player1.letter)
  console.log(player2.name)
  console.log(player2.letter)
  document.querySelector('.board').style = ('display: flex;')
  document.querySelector('.nameInput').style = ('display: none;')
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name}'s turn`;
  document.querySelector('.display').style = ('font-size: 2em;');
  playGame()
})

const gameGrid = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

let currentPlayer = '';
let playerTurn = 1;
let gameOver = false;

//Function to take turns switching from player 1 to player 2, starting with player 1. Display div displays whose turn it is once the current player has just taken a turn.
const takeTurns = () => {
  if (playerTurn === 1) {
    currentPlayer = player1.letter;
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player2.name}'s turn`;
    playerTurn = 0;
  } else if (playerTurn === 0) {
    currentPlayer = player2.letter;
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name}'s turn`;
    playerTurn = 1;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

const player1WinDisplay = () => {
  console.log(`${player1.name} wins!`)
  console.log('game over')
  gameOver = true;
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name} wins!`;
  return null
}

const player2WinDisplay = () => {
  console.log(`${player2.name} wins!`)
  console.log('game over')
  gameOver = true;
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player2.name} wins!`;
  return null
}

const determineWinner = () => {
  if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[1] && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[1]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X' && gameGrid[1] == 'X' && gameGrid[2] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[3] != '' && gameGrid[3] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[5] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[3] == 'X' && gameGrid[4] == 'X' && gameGrid[5] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[6] != '' && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[7] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[7]) {
    if (gameGrid[6] == 'X' && gameGrid[7] == 'X' && gameGrid[8] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[3] && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[3]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X' && gameGrid[3] == 'X' && gameGrid[6] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[1] != '' && gameGrid[1] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[7] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[1] == 'X' && gameGrid[4] == 'X' && gameGrid[7] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[2] != '' && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[5] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[5]) {
    if (gameGrid[2] == 'X' && gameGrid[5] == 'X' && gameGrid[8] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X' && gameGrid[4] == 'X' && gameGrid[8] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[6] != '' && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[6] == 'X' && gameGrid[4] == 'X' && gameGrid[2] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] && gameGrid[1] && gameGrid[2] && gameGrid[3] && gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[5] && gameGrid[6] && gameGrid[7] && gameGrid[8] != '') {
    console.log('Draw')
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `It's a draw`;
    return null
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

  squares.forEach((square) => {

    const a1 = document.querySelector('#a1');
    const a2 = document.querySelector('#a2');
    const a3 = document.querySelector('#a3');
    const b1 = document.querySelector('#b1');
    const b2 = document.querySelector('#b2');
    const b3 = document.querySelector('#b3');
    const c1 = document.querySelector('#c1');
    const c2 = document.querySelector('#c2');
    const c3 = document.querySelector('#c3');

    square.addEventListener('click', () => {
      //Locks in div display and array if div has been clicked; prevents takeTurns and turn display from changing if clicking on filled square
      determineWinner()
      if (square.textContent != '') {
        return
      } else if (square.textContent == '' && gameOver == false) {
        takeTurns()
        if (square == a1) {
          gameGrid[0] = currentPlayer;
          a1.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == b1) {
          gameGrid[1] = currentPlayer;
          b1.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == c1) {
          gameGrid[2] = currentPlayer;
          c1.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == a2) {
          gameGrid[3] = currentPlayer;
          a2.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == b2) {
          gameGrid[4] = currentPlayer;
          b2.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == c2) {
          gameGrid[5] = currentPlayer;
          c2.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == a3) {
          gameGrid[6] = currentPlayer;
          a3.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == b3) {
          gameGrid[7] = currentPlayer;
          b3.textContent = currentPlayer;

        } else if (square == c3) {
          gameGrid[8] = currentPlayer;
          c3.textContent = currentPlayer;

        }
        console.log(gameGrid);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.board {
  display: none;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}

#a1,
#b1,
#c1 {
  border-top: none;
}

#a3,
#b3,
#c3 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#a1,
#a2,
#a3 {
  border-left: none;
}

#c1,
#c2,
#c3 {
  border-right: none;
}

#player1Name {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

#player2Name {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      <div class="display">
        <form action="nameInput" class="nameInput">
          <label for="player1Name">Player 1 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="player1Name" name="player1Name" required>
          <label for="player2Name">Player 2 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="player2Name" name="player2Name" required>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit / Start">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <div class="columnA">
        <div class="square" id="a1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="a2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="a3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnB">
        <div class="square" id="b1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="b2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="b3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnC">
        <div class="square" id="c1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="c2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="c3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried calling the function in various places but will either not work or not work as needed.

Comment: You have to call `determineWinner()` *after* you update the grid for the current click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `determineWinner()` before you add the current play to `gameGrid`.

You can simplify the event listener code greatly. Instead of lots of `if` statements, use the current index in the `squares` array as the index into `gameGrid`. This is passed as the second argument to the `forEach()` callback function.

In `determineWinner()`, once you've determined that 3 in a row are the same, you only need to check one of them to tell which player is the winner.

```js
const addPlayer = (name, letter) => {
  return {
    name,
    letter
  };
}

//Form creates players and if names are left blank, will make names "Player 1" and "Player 2" by default.
//Will start the game upon clicking submit and hide the form in place of a game display
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  player1 = addPlayer(document.querySelector('#player1Name').value, 'X');
  if (player1.name == '') {
    player1.name = 'Player 1'
  }
  player2 = addPlayer(document.querySelector('#player2Name').value, 'O');
  if (player2.name == '') {
    player2.name = 'Player 2'
  }
  console.log(player1.name)
  console.log(player1.letter)
  console.log(player2.name)
  console.log(player2.letter)
  document.querySelector('.board').style = ('display: flex;')
  document.querySelector('.nameInput').style = ('display: none;')
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name}'s turn`;
  document.querySelector('.display').style = ('font-size: 2em;');
  playGame()
})

const gameGrid = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

let currentPlayer = '';
let playerTurn = 1;
let gameOver = false;

//Function to take turns switching from player 1 to player 2, starting with player 1. Display div displays whose turn it is once the current player has just taken a turn.
const takeTurns = () => {
  if (playerTurn === 1) {
    currentPlayer = player1.letter;
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player2.name}'s turn`;
    playerTurn = 0;
  } else if (playerTurn === 0) {
    currentPlayer = player2.letter;
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name}'s turn`;
    playerTurn = 1;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

const player1WinDisplay = () => {
  console.log(`${player1.name} wins!`)
  console.log('game over')
  gameOver = true;
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player1.name} wins!`;
  return null
}

const player2WinDisplay = () => {
  console.log(`${player2.name} wins!`)
  console.log('game over')
  gameOver = true;
  document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `${player2.name} wins!`;
  return null
}

const determineWinner = () => {
  if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[1] && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[1]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[3] != '' && gameGrid[3] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[5] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[3] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[6] != '' && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[7] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[7]) {
    if (gameGrid[6] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[3] && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[3]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[1] != '' && gameGrid[1] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[7] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[1] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[2] != '' && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[5] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[5]) {
    if (gameGrid[2] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] != '' && gameGrid[0] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[8] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[0] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[6] != '' && gameGrid[6] == gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[2] == gameGrid[4]) {
    if (gameGrid[6] == 'X') {
      player1WinDisplay()
    } else {
      player2WinDisplay()
    }
  } else if (gameGrid[0] && gameGrid[1] && gameGrid[2] && gameGrid[3] && gameGrid[4] && gameGrid[5] && gameGrid[6] && gameGrid[7] && gameGrid[8] != '') {
    console.log('Draw')
    document.querySelector('.display').textContent = `It's a draw`;
  }
}

const playGame = () => {
  let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

  squares.forEach((square, index) => {
    square.addEventListener('click', () => {
      //Locks in div display and array if div has been clicked; prevents takeTurns and turn display from changing if clicking on filled square
      if (gameOver || square.textContent != '') {
        return;
      }

      takeTurns();
      gameGrid[index] = currentPlayer;
      square.textContent = currentPlayer;
      determineWinner();
      console.log(gameGrid);
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.board {
  display: none;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}

#a1,
#b1,
#c1 {
  border-top: none;
}

#a3,
#b3,
#c3 {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#a1,
#a2,
#a3 {
  border-left: none;
}

#c1,
#c2,
#c3 {
  border-right: none;
}

#player1Name {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

#player2Name {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
      <div class="display">
        <form action="nameInput" class="nameInput">
          <label for="player1Name">Player 1 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="player1Name" name="player1Name" required>
          <label for="player2Name">Player 2 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="player2Name" name="player2Name" required>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit / Start">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      <div class="columnA">
        <div class="square" id="a1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="a2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="a3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnB">
        <div class="square" id="b1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="b2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="b3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnC">
        <div class="square" id="c1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="c2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="c3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```